Unity HDRP Additional Camera Affecting Scene Lighting and Colors Issue with Volume Mask (Unity 2022.3.36f1)
I'm encountering an issue with an additional camera affecting the lighting and colors of my scene in Unity 2022.3.36f1 using HDRP. I've imported an HDRP sample scene and added a new camera specifically for UI elements. Here's what I've tried:
Camera Settings:
    Rendering -> Culling Mask = UI (also tried "Nothing")
    Environment -> Background Type = None
    Environment -> Volume Mask = Nothing
    Environment -> Probe Layer Mask = Nothing
    Depth = 1 (higher than the main scene camera)

Despite these settings, enabling or disabling this UI camera changes the scene's brightness and colors.
Additional Issue:
When I set Environment -> Volume Mask = Everything, the UI camera no longer affects the scene's lighting, but a portion of the skybox? (or something resembling clouds) appears in the lower half of the screen. Disabling all Volumes in the sample project's Volumes object doesn't resolve either issue.
Questions:

Why is this additional camera affecting the scene's lighting, even with the settings above?
How can I prevent a UI camera from impacting the overall scene's appearance without causing the skybox issue?
Are there other settings or configurations I should investigate to address these problems?

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this. Thank you!

After further investigation, In the HDRP sample scene, disabling Tonemapping and Bloom in the Global Volume seems to prevent the UI camera from affecting the main scene's lighting, even with "Background Type" set to "None." However, these two settings appear to ignore the camera's mask settings.
I'm curious as to why this happens and if there's a better way to manage this in HDRP. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
